# mvn -version is not returning the version

Tags: maven

`java -version` is working fine :

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

after configuring Maven, `mvn -version` is not appearing.

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly This environment variable is needed to run this program NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK, not a JRE 'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/install.html):

> Ensure JAVA_HOME environment variable is set and points to your JDK installation

For example:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

You should generally get a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable configured as a result of installing your JDK. But else you can create it by hand.